# Database connection error in Yii

Tags: yii

I'm going through the Yii tutorial on creating a blog and following the steps. For the database I just imported the test database. Everything was fine.

When I made connection with the database in main.php it is showing the following error:

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'myblog'

The database connection array in main.php is:

```
//'db'=>array(
//  'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
//),
// uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myblog',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'ia_',
),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using the MySQL command line tool?

Comment: is there a database in your mysql named "myblog"? And is your mysql root user password is actually "root"?? Please check it once again. Linux/Unix systems are case-sensitive for database names also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you following this Yii Blog tutorial?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.database

Are you using MySQL database or just SQLite?  The DBName is blog, not myblog on this page.

Tip: If you want to use MySQL instead of SQLite to store data, you may create a MySQL database named blog using the SQL statements in /wwwroot/yii/demos/blog/protected/data/schema.mysql.sql. Then, modify the application configuration as follows,

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ),
    ),
  ......
);
```

Answer (score 1):

note to the following error while there is your database!
SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database ' test :host=localhost

there is a problem in php code

Wrong code

> > $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:dbname=shenakht', "mehdi", "1");

Correct code

> > $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shenakht', "mehdi", "1");

The difference between is : and ;

if your code is correct go to the http://localhost/phpmyadmin and create database!